# How to pass arguments to the python script that is running inside docker container?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, parameter-passing

I'm running python script inside docker container. Depending on the passed parameters my script should show different information. I want to pass this parameter trough the `docker run {my_image_name} {parameters}` command, where instead {parameters} i want to type some custom values that my script expects  to  receive. Found some info about arguments and env variables, but don`t understand it. Can anybody explain how to do it resolving my issue? What should i add to dockerfile?
Dockerfile content:

```
FROM python:3.8.2-buster
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY metrics.py .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python -m pip install psutil
CMD python /usr/src/app/metrics.py
```

When i'm running docker run {my_image_name} {my_script_name} {parameter} i'm getting:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"metrics.py\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

I work on windows.

Comment: You need to either add a shebang to your script or pass “python” as the first parameter to your docker run command before the script name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing ENTRYPOINT

Docker file should be something like this:

```
FROM python:3.8.2-buster
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY metrics.py .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python -m pip install psutil
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["/usr/src/app/metrics.py"]
```

Comment: Why split the interpreter from the program this way?  If you put both words in the `ENTRYPOINT` then this supports the "container-as-command" style (`docker run imagename --option`); with this split you still have to write the script name like it was the command to run, but you've limited yourself to only running Python scripts (not `docker run --rm -it imagename bash` for example).